# Are we gonna wear fancy WINTER Bash hats forever?

Tags: discussion

I see people including me wearing fancy hats , cool things with their profile pic.My question is -> **Are we gonna wear these cool things forever** ? Thanks for spending time answering my question.

For those people who dont realise what I am talking about , please have look at the fancy hat by Sir Jon skeet (Black hat I am talking about).

[image: This is i am talking about]

Answer (score 2):

No. See the [Winter Bash FAQ](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/faq):

> After January 4th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

Comment: Was it a bad idea to wear hats Forever?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.JAVA.net If we would get them forever, Winter Bash wouldn't be a special event anymore.